# npm install failes with ERR! tar.unpack (raspi)

Tags: node.js, selenium, raspberry-pi

I try to install Selenium Code Line Runner following this tutorial

https://www.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/docs/en/introduction/command-line-runner/

I managed to `sudo apt-get install nodejs` and  `sudo apt-get install npm`
but I failed with installing selenium-side-runner via `sudo npm install -g selenium-side-runner`

I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! tar.unpack ...
```

See also: [error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwPY2.png)

I stumbled upon some tricks as follows:

- Installation to SD Card (Raspi)
- Card is not full
- `sudo npm cache clean` and retry didn't work
- `sudo rm -r /usr/local/lib/node_modules/selenium-side-runner` and retry didn't work

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

An update of NPM did it!

```
sudo npm install -g npm@latest
```